# Definition for Basis of a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, hamel-basis

As I gradually work through the fundamentals of linear algebra, I have often found myself struggling with boiling down the concepts that I have learned to a concise, all encompassing definition which can be summed up in no more than a couple of sentences.

I am currently learning about bases for vector spaces, and for this I seek clarification of my definition from Stack Exchange members.

From what I have learned so far, the concisest definition that I can provide for this concept is the following:

A basis of a subspace is a set of vectors which can be used to represent any other vector in the subspace.

Thus the set must:

- Be linearly independent.
- Span all of the subspace.
- Not include any vectors which are linearly dependent upon other vectors in the set.

Is this definition accurate? If not; where did I misspeak? And is there any crucial information that I missed?

Comment: The third bullet is redundant, it follows from the first. Otherwise the list is ok.

Comment: A subspace is a vector space. So the definition of the basis of a subspace is the same as the definition of the basis of a vector space.

Comment: @Bernard Massé Yes I know that they are the same thing. I just used the terms 'basis of vector space' and 'basis of a subspace' interchangeably.

Comment: The answer given below by @BrianBorchers makes an important point.  The correct statement is, "A basis of a subspace is a set of vectors that can be used to *uniquely* represent any vector in the subspace."

Comment: @RobertShore Apologies Robert, but I am not really seeing the significance of adding the word 'uniquely' to the definition. Could you perhaps try to expand on this?

Comment: The word "uniquely" is why you need linear independence.  Otherwise you could throw every single vector into the set to be sure you can represent all of the vectors.  That's not a basis because (since the set isn't linearly independent) the representation wouldn't be unique.

Comment: @RobertShore So when we say 'unique', we are really referring to the number of vectors in the set, not that there is only one set of vectors which can be used to represent any given vector in the subspace?

Comment: No.  We are saying that for any vector in your space, there is a *unique* linear combination of vectors in the basis that sum to your vector.  To see that this is the same as linear independence, assume you have two different linear representations of the same vector, and take the difference.  You'll end up with a non-trivial linear combination of basis vectors that sum to $0$, contradicting linear independence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97371/discussion-between-ryan-walter-and-robert-shore).

Answer (score 3):

Your first and third conditions assert the same thing. Therefore, I would keep just the first (it is the shortest one) and the second one. If you want to be more concise, you can say that a basis of a vector space is a linearly independet spanning subset of that space.

Answer (score 0):

"Thus" in your statement doesn't actually include any justification.  The reason that you want the basis vectors to be linearly independent is so that each vector in the subspace can be *uniquely* represented as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "In order to achieve this, the set must:" rather than "thus, the set must:". But not really sure that the use of the word "thus" a big deal to be honest in the context of my question.

Comment: Aside from that, could you clarify the significance of adding the word 'uniquely'?

Comment: Suppose that vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$ span a subspace $S$ of $R^{3}$, but $w=u+v$.  The vector $z=3u+2v+0w$ can also be written as $z=u+0v+2w$.  This means that "coordinates of $z$ with respect to $u$, $v$, $w$" aren't well defined.